# How can I have Spotify play music instead of iTunes when pressing the play/F8 key on MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, spotify, wireless-keyboard

When I turn on my MBP the first thing I do is play some Spotify music and I got it loaded on startup, although when I press play/F8 which is play button on keyboard iTunes pops up.

Even with the Spotify app opened, pressing play/F8 key still launches iTunes app. The only way this works is if music has been played in Spotify and then paused or stopped, then pressing play/F8 key plays music with Spotify. Is it possible to make the play/F8 key open Spotify rather than iTunes every time it is pressed?

I tried many things, including external apps but not fixing my problem.

I use my MacBook Pro 16 connected to an external thunderbolt monitor, and the laptop is flipped down, using only the wireless bluetooth Apple Magic Keyboard as main keyboard.

Running latest version of MacOS Monterey 12.3 on MacBook Pro 16 and using an external Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad - French Canadian.

Thanks

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58234/override-itunes-media-keys-play-pause-etc-for-spotify

Comment: All the solutions offered in this 10 year old post, are either not working or not every time. I also tried 3rd party apps like BeardedSpice but unless you launch Spotify first, they won't work. I am looking for a smooth solution that works every single time, and if possible, without a 3rd party app. I also put Spotify in my login items so it starts up at restart and power on, but a lot of times I closed it when not using it and then the problem occurs again, I have to launch Spotify 1st...

Comment: Finding a native solution will probably be tough. I imagine a 3rd party app will be needed. I tried BeardedSpice before posting the link and the only issue is making sure Spotify is running like you mentioned. If you're closing Spotify with ⌘+Q then you're a bit out of luck. If you're using the red x, there's is an option within Spotify that says `Close button should minimize Spotify window`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue on my MacBook Air (Monterey) by going to system preferences>accessibility>motor>keyboard>enable full keyboard access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).